# Navigating to folders in OS X Terminal Issue

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to navigate from Documents to Development to MeDevelopment using the cd command in Terminal.

For some reason it's not allowing me to navigate to the MeDevelopment folder where I have an Xcode folder saved which I need to navigate to in terminal. I've also tried the other folders. I looked on google and elsewhere and couldn't find anything helpful.

Im using El Capitan on OS X. I downloaded Parse Cloud Data using terminal. Could it possibly be a bug on their side which, when using *sudo commands*, created a bug on my machine?

Here's the error: [image: Am i using the wrong command (cd) from the Development folder? I just don't get it.]

Please let me know if i can provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I typed cd MeDev and hit tab for auto-complete. Then this showed up:

```
cd MeDevelopment\ /
```

Which put me into that folder. Still strange that I couldn't navigate to the folder without the auto-complete...

Problem was that I had a space after MeDevelopment. Explanation thanks to: @josh.chavanne

Comment: Looks like you have a space after MeDevelopment - if you aren't tied to that path too much I'd say delete it.

Comment: Love to help!  Those pesky spaces!